# Unit testing methods containing AWSAPIGatewayResponse in swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-api-gateway

I have the following method and I'm trying to unit test this in iOS/Swift

```
func apiResponseResults(response: AWSAPIGatewayResponse, sessionObject: Session) {
    if response.statusCode == 200 {
        // code
    } else {
        // code
    }
}
```

This method is called from my api `invoke` method when the response is received. I want to unit test this by creating a fake `AWSAPIGatewayResponse` object.
I am not able to create `AWSAPIGatewayResponse` object. Is there a way to initialize this object in my unit testing class. I just wanna create an `AWSAPIGatewayResponse` object with statusCode as `200` and `300`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Pradeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11373446/pradeep), welcome to StackOverflow.

You could define a protocol with the subset of functionality you are interested in from `AWSAPIGatewayResponse`, make `AWSAPIGatewayResponse` conform to it, and make  `apiResponseResults(response:, session:)` expect a value of that type.

```
protocol Response {
  var statusCode: Int { get }
}

extension AWSAPIGatewayResponse: Response { }

func apiResponseResults(response: Response, sessionObject: Session) { ... }
```

In your tests your can define a test double conforming to `Response`, and use that as the input parameter for your method.

```
struct TestResponse: Response {
  let statusCode: Int
}

// Use it like this
let response = TestResponse(statusCode: 200)
```

Hope this helps.